# Get product inventory list from Magento API v2 using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, api, magento, magento-1.7

Just figured out how to get a sessionid back using `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v2_soap?wsdl` and nothing seems to work.  The code below returns the following:

Line that has error:
prodListRequest = ws.catalogProductList(sessionId, filter, "")

Error returned:
Value of type '1-dimensional array of CompanyADevMagento.catalogProductEntity' cannot be converted to 'MagentoService.catalogProductReturnEntity'.

Does anyone have a asp.net vb example of getting inventory list?

Thanks.

```
Imports CompanyADevMagento
Imports System.Xml

Partial Class site_magento
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim sessionId As String = ""

Protected Sub btnShowData_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowData.Click
    Dim ws As New CompanyAMagento.MagentoService
    Dim sOutput As String = ""

    sessionId = ws.login("username", "yourapipassword")
    litOutput.Text = "Session: " & sessionId

    Try
        Dim filter As New filters
        Dim prodListRequest As New MagentoService.catalogProductReturnEntity
        prodListRequest = ws.catalogProductList(sessionId, filter, "")

    Catch ex As Exception
        litError.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

-Magento Version using: 1.7.0.2
-Currently set Magento Core API > WS-I Compliance = Yes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with ASP, however it looks to me that your code is expecting the wrong object type.

The `catalogProductList` API method returns an instance of `catalogProductEntity`, while your code seems to expect `catalogProductReturnEntity`.

The latter is returned from the `catalogProductInfo` method.

[CatalogProductEntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bZCv.png)

[CatalogProductReturnEntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRU3f.png)

From the docs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html